# Vue updating all components in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuejs2

In my component the `v-for` displays all items in the `allItems` array brought from firestore.

Add the end of there as an Add button so that the user can add an item to his basket for that I have an array set up in store set up in which the items get added to.

I have a `v-if` on that button show the message **Item Added** when clicked for that particular item in which `itemAdded` becomes true. So that the **Item Added** message can be shown and the button dissapears.

But when I click the button all the items show the message **Item Added**.

I want only the particular item to show the message. Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

**The Component**

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" v-for="(item) in allItems" :key="item.ITEM_NAME">
  <v-card
          class="d-flex flex-row disableScroll"
          flat
          tile
          style="margin-top: 16px; padding: 2px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <v-card max-width="250">
      <v-img
              class="white--text align-end"
              height="200px"
              src="../../assets/img/category_blank.jpg"
      >
        <v-card-title>{{item.ITEM_NAME}}</v-card-title>
      </v-img>

      <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0">{{item.ITEM_DESC}}</v-card-subtitle>

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-card-text>Rs {{item.ITEM_PRICE}}</v-card-text>
        <v-btn v-if="item.ITEM_STOCK && !itemAdded" style="margin-left: auto" color="orange" text @click="addItem(item)">
          Add
        </v-btn>
        <p v-else-if="itemAdded">Item Added</p>
        <p v-else> Out of Stock</p>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-card>
  </v-col>
```

**The Script**

```
<script>
import {db, getStoreID} from "@/main";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allItems: [],
      orderItems: {},
      itemAdded: false,
    }
  },
  name: "HomeCategories",
  props: ["category"],
  created() {
    let docID = getStoreID();
    db.collection("STORES")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("ITEMS")
        .doc("DATA")
        .collection(this.$props.category).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.allItems.push(doc.data())
          })
    })
  },

  methods: {
     addItem(item){
      this.orderItems.name = item.ITEM_NAME,
    this.orderItems.price =  item.ITEM_PRICE,
    this.orderItems.isAvail =  item.ITEM_AVAILABLE,
    this.orderItems.imgUrl = item.ITEM_IMG_URL,
    this.orderItems.quantity = 1,
   this.itemAdded = true
   this.$store.commit("ADD_ITEM_TO_BASKET", this.orderItems);
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are checking condition instead of `itemAdded` as boolean, make it as an Array

create a new function in `methods` like this

```
isItemAdded(value) {
    if (this.itemAdded.includes(value)) {
          return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

now, in the `addItem` function add the value to array `this.itemAdded` like this

```
this.itemAdded.push(item);
```

Changes in the HTML

```
<v-btn v-if="item.ITEM_STOCK && !isItemAdded(item)" style="margin-left: auto" 
color="orange" text @click="addItem(item)">
              Add
            </v-btn>
            <p v-else-if="isItemAdded(item)">Item Added</p>
```

And you are all set. Cheers

Comment: Your method worked but u cannot add parameters in the functions that are computed, I had to declare `isItemAdded` in `methods`. You can update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `itemAdded` value is boolean, so it has only 2 values: true and false, but you use it for **every** item, so if you change it then you change it for every item.

1. This option for only 1 item can be added.

You should be more precise. For example, you can keep item name in `itemAdded`, so you will always know what item was added. In that case only **one** item can have this flag.

2. This option if every item can be added once.

Another option is to treat `itemAdded` as array, so every item can be added (once).

First, change component data to have `itemsAdded` to be array:

```js
...
data() {
    return {
      allItems: [],
      orderItems: {},
      itemAdded: [], // <--- here we change itemAdded to be array
    }
  },
...
```

Now we need to check `itemAdded` not as boolean, but as array of boolean:

```html
...
<v-btn v-if="item.ITEM_STOCK && !itemAdded[item.ITEM_NAME]"
...
<p v-else-if="itemAdded[item.ITEM_NAME]">Item Added</p>
...
```

And finally we change the flag for item on button click:

```js
...
methods: {
  addItem(item){
    ...
    this.itemAdded[item.ITEM_NAME] = true; // <--- see array here?
    ...
```

If you need, I can add some code examples.

Comment: it would be helpful if you added code examples  as I am new to this.

Comment: @SaaranshMenon I've added examples for the second option. Hope, you will understand what lines you need to change in your code :)

Comment: I did the changes but now when I click the button the message does not show.

Comment: @SaaranshMenon sure, because one place I've forgot: `<p v-else-if="itemAdded">Item Added</p>`. I've updated my answer

Comment: The items are being added but the message still does not show after I click the button.

Comment: @SaaranshMenon I do not see your code now and I can't test it... Maybe you could add some debug info. For example add `<div>{{itemAdded}}</div>` before `<v-col ...` just to see what is inside the `itemAdded` variable?